# Why do base and overlay only match at scale 1:1000 and 1:2000?

Tags: geoserver, scale

We are using GEOSERVER 2.1.4 to  overlay WMS on GoogleMaps V3 with Openlayers .

The problem we have is at different zoom levels the scale of the WMS overlay is different from the scale of the base layer.

It is only at scale 1:1000 and 1:2000 that overlay and base layer coincide.

Any suggestions?

The part of the code:

```
        var map;
        var untiled;
        var tiled;
        var pureCoverage = false;
    OpenLayers.Lang.setCode('el');  
        // pink tile avoidance
        OpenLayers.IMAGE_RELOAD_ATTEMPTS = 5;
        // make OL compute scale according to WMS spec
        OpenLayers.DOTS_PER_INCH = 25.4 / 0.28;

        function map_reg_init(){
            // if this is just a coverage or a group of them, disable a few items,
            // and default to jpeg format
            format = 'image/png';
            if(pureCoverage) {
                document.getElementById('filterType').disabled = true;
                document.getElementById('filter').disabled = true;
                document.getElementById('antialiasSelector').disabled = true;
                document.getElementById('updateFilterButton').disabled = true;
                document.getElementById('resetFilterButton').disabled = true;
                document.getElementById('jpeg').selected = true;
                format = "image/jpeg";
            }
    var projEGSA=new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:2100");
    var projLONLAT = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
        var projGOOGLE=new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913");
            var bounds = new OpenLayers.Bounds(
                2327363.1529655424, 4805801.76429202,
                2328463.0753220413, 4806793.842097636
            );
    var scales = [500, 1000, 2000, 4000, 5000, 10000, 15000, 25000, 50000];
    var resolutions = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < scales.length; i++) {
        resolutions.push(OpenLayers.Util.getResolutionFromScale(scales[i], 'm'));
    }

            var options = {
                controls: [],
                maxExtent: bounds,
        scales: scales,     
                maxResolution: 156543.0339,
            numZoomLevels    : 22,
                allOverlays      : true,    
                projection: "EPSG:900913",
                units: 'm'
            };
    var mousePointerStyle = 'default';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"google maps" has pre-defined scales with 20 pre-defined zoom Levels.

I am no expert, but maybe [What ratio scales do Google Maps zoom levels correspond to?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7430) is a hint:

```
20 : 1128.497220
19 : 2256.994440
18 : 4513.988880
17 : 9027.977761
16 : 18055.955520
15 : 36111.911040
14 : 72223.822090
13 : 144447.644200
12 : 288895.288400
11 : 577790.576700
10 : 1155581.153000
9  : 2311162.307000
8  : 4622324.614000
7  : 9244649.227000
6  : 18489298.450000
5  : 36978596.910000
4  : 73957193.820000
3  : 147914387.600000
2  : 295828775.300000
1  : 591657550.500000
```