# Google maps distance based on the zoom level

Tags: google-maps, distance, google-maps-api, zoom

I have used google maps for displaying some locations using `markers`, based on the user's current location. User's current location is the center point of the map. The default `zoom level` is `12`. In default, I displayed markers within `300 miles`(In my case) distance only.

In that how can I do the following,

1) If decrease the zoom level, I need to increase the distance that should display markers within the increased distance also. how much distance should I increase in miles (For e.g. `Zoom level` is `11`) ?

2) If increase the zoom level, I need to  decrease the distance that should display markers without the increased distance. how much distance should I decrease in miles (For e.g. `Zoom level` is `13`) ?

Please suggest me there is any built-in option to do that ...

Comment: What's the meaning of this `300 Miles`? Is it just the distance from the center point to the boder of the map? If yes, you could double the distance for zoom level 12 and take half the distance for zoom level 13. cf. [What ratio scales do Google Maps zoom levels correspond to?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7430/what-ratio-scales-do-google-maps-zoom-levels-correspond-to)

Answer (score 1):

Check out this question, it has answers with equations and explanations for the different zoom levels.
[What ratio scales do Google Maps zoom levels correspond to?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7430/what-ratio-scales-do-google-maps-zoom-levels-correspond-to)