# How can I tile a region in Google Maps given a zoom level

Tags: google-maps

I am searching for a way to generate a tiling of a grid region using Google Maps. I have found a way to [generate a grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40342355/how-can-i-generate-a-regular-geographic-grid-using-python) and as well as a reference for [pixel to width ratios given a zoom level](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7430/what-ratio-scales-do-google-maps-zoom-levels-correspond-to), but I conceptually can't put them together.

Assuming I retrieve a static map from Google that I know the centre (lat,lon), zoom and dimensions (pixels), could someone point me in the right direction to calculate the coordinates at the centre of the 4 edges of my view or the centre of the next tile?

[image]

Comment: [@chris](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/86165/chris), have you seen this article [google maps tiles' center coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25990570/get-center-latlng-point-of-a-custom-tile-in-google-maps-api-v3/25991835#25991835)?