# Calculate offline map download size for a square km for each zoom level?

Tags: google-maps, openmaptiles

I am working on estimation of how much will I have to download to make maps available offine at different zoom levels. What I am looking for is something like below.

```
zoomLevel,sizeInKM,downloadInGB
1,1,0.065
2,1,0.5
```

I have read different articles from OpenStreetMaps, Google Maps API and Bing Maps. References below, none of them talk about how to relate size to kilometers.

[What ratio scales do Google Maps zoom levels correspond to?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7430/what-ratio-scales-do-google-maps-zoom-levels-correspond-to)

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/articles/bing-maps-tile-system

https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Zoom_levels

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238611/how-can-i-get-tile-count-tile-x-tile-y-details-without-specifying-zoom-level

If someone has experience with maps, can you show me a direction to get some download size estimates for 1 km square block on a map at different zoom levels for offline viewing.

Answer (score -1):

The below answer gives a bit of an idea on how to start estimating the size of the download. Which this is good for a starting point, I will keep looking.

[Tileset Article](https://www.microimages.com/documentation/TechGuides/78googleMapsStruc.pdf)